# Use Com class from LocalSystem

Tags: .net, com, windows-services

I'm using a Com object. The com server should be used from a Windows service running as a specific account. But when running in this account it can't load the com, giving me this exception: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {36998A63-857C-4B87-BC5E-72B7B3573F80} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010105.

I tried changing the account to LocalSystem, that still fails, but changing the Windows service to log on as my own account works.

I guess it has to do with the com server being installed on my account. I install the com using "it's name.exe /regserver". I tried running the command as LocalSystem and it then fails with an assert. I don't have the code, so I don't know where the problem is, is there a permission I should should check?
I also tried switching embed interop type in Visual Studio.

Any help?

Comment: Have you set activation rights with DCOM Config?

Comment: Hi sharptooth. I don't know what that is, so probably not

Comment: I started DCOMCNFG.EXE and tried to find it, but I couldn't

Comment: You have to open "component services" -> "this computer" -> "DCOM config", locate you out-proc COM server there and adjust its settings.

Comment: The trick is that I'm running Windows 64 bit and the com server is 32, so I need to run it like MMC comexp.msc /32 to see it. Make it an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing is `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT`, which means that there has been a unhandled Win32 exception (e.g. perhaps an access violation) in the out-of-process COM server. If you have neither source code nor debug symbols for the COM server, you're unlikely to be able to diagnose this or fix it yourself. (EDIT: Unless it's something obvious like a mismatch of "bitness" on a 64-bit machine :-))

Options:

- if you ought to be able to activate
  the server and consume its COM
  objects in the context of your
  service's account, then you will need
  to raise this with the vendor of the
  server and get them to diagnose and
  fix it;
- you can use DCOMCNFG.EXE    (Identity
  tab) to configure the COM    server
  to run under your identity    instead
  of the default (which is "the launching user"), and see whether this avoids the faulting problem (it sounds from what you say that it probably will).

Comment: Actually since the problem is likely in lack of some rights he could use Process Monitor to try diagnose the problem.

Comment: @sharptooth: I may be wrong (there is no official Microsoft documentation) but in my experience RPC_E_SERVERFAULT generally indicates a more fundamental problem in the server implementation such as an access violation or divide by zero error. A lack of required permissions would normally show up as an HRESULT of E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005). By all means see whether Process Monitor can tell you anything, but I'm not sure what you'd be looking for.

Comment: ... or a mismatch of "bitness" :-)

Comment: Changing the identity to "Interactive user" (or setting my account explicit) works, so I can not run the windows service as the account I want. That' great, but why must the local com server run as it? Will I experience problems when running it on Windows Server 2003 ? I guess there won't be an interactive user available all the time?

Comment: @Karsten: I suggested changing the identity for the COM server, not the identity for the Windows service - which could still run under the service account. I don't know whether this gives you what you want or not - I'm just trying to suggest a workaround for the SERVERFAULT exception. You certainly should avoid "interactive user" if the service might be calling the COM component when there is no one logged in.

Comment: The windows service account is as it should be now. It's the com server that's interactive, and I don't understand why it has to be interactive.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this, from our friend [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), on a Microsoft newsgroup thread. It's so good and pertinent I hope Hans won't mind me quoting it.

> Ah, the dreaded RPC_E_SERVERFAULT. 
>   RPC installs an SEH handler in the
>   stub that catches any SEH exception
>   the occurs in the COM server.  Even
>   the really bad ones like AV.  The
>   client is notified about the exception
>   with 0x80010105.  Which is awful,
>   there's no way to get any information
>   whatsoever about the exception.  Even
>   worse, the server just keeps running,
>   now typically with a radically messed
>   up internal state due to the
>   exception.  There's nothing you can do
>   about it but trying to debug the COM
>   server to find out why it is throwing
>   exceptions.  If it is a black box to
>   you, you'll have a heck of a time
>   without support from the COM component
>   vendor.